# Loading Connection String in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, connection-string

I have a webAPI application that I am trying to secure its connection string to the database. In the connection string I have replaced Sever, User and Password with place holders. The placeholders are keys whose values are encrypted Server, User and password as below.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*", 
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=[SV];Initial Catalog=BILLING;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[UI];Password=[PW];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;",
    "SV": "zkyj5mpIrHFTW7G6TCn7VriSRFzTakIVwGmMwME1kw", 
    "UI": "PSEQqm6qj9cx944FzhIrdQ==",
    "PW": "NpfObfbydTZK+pmAsVlFn8xoj8L4irtVd988+emYyw="

  }

}
```

In program.cs I have the following:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddScoped<ISecurity, Security>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ConnectionSecurity>();

var conn = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var server = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SV");
var pass = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PW");
var user = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("UI");

var sec = new ConnectionSecurity(new Security());
var connectionString = sec.BuildConnectionString(conn,server,user,pass); 



builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContextBilling>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

The ConnectionSecurity class has the following method.

```
public string BuildConnectionString(string con,string Server,string User,string Pass)
        {
            string connString = con;

            Server = DecryptCredentials(Server);
            User = DecryptCredentials(User);
            Pass = DecryptCredentials(Pass);

            connString = connString.Replace("[SV]", Server);
            connString = connString.Replace("[UI]", User);
            connString = connString.Replace("[PW]", Pass);


            return connString;
        }
```

The application compiles fine and the place holders in connection string get decrypted and replaced properly. The connectionString passed to `x.UseSqlServer(connectionString)` is correct.
The problem arises when I make a request for an item in database, the following errors are caught in the Event Viewer:

```
1.RequestPath: /api/v1/AccessRight/GetProfileCategories
ActionId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ActionName: BillingWebAPI.Controllers.AccessRightController.GetProfileCategories (BillingWebAPI)

An error occurred using the connection to database 'BILLING' on server '[SV]'.

2.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Even if I replace the connectionSting being passed to be an empty string, `x.UseSqlServer("")`, I still get the above errors. I have cleaned and rebuilt the application a number of times but still getting the errors. If the connection string is plain, with the server, user and password, then the request goes through and I get the results from the database.
Kindly assist me understand where and how the connection string is loaded in the application? And other ways of Securing the connection string?

Comment: What is it you are trying to protect against? If your application will need the connection string in clear text. And if it can get it, a competent attacker with access to the machine can as well. Protection of connection strings is usually more of a concern in other places, like source code repositories. So I would either just use clear text passwords, or some other authentication mechanism, depending on what your server supports.

Comment: If you are certain the string is passed correctly then maybe it's in your `AddDbContext`. Somebody could have overridden the default behavior to get the connection string from the configuration instead of using the one passed as parameter.

Comment: The error says the server cannot be found.  Either the server is not running, you are using the wrong server name. or the connection is timing out (possible TLS certificate issue).  Your server is Server=[SV] in the connection string.  Try connecting with SQL Server Management Studio.  The server\instance is in the login window.  SQL server has two credentials 1) Windows 2) SQL.  If using windows you have to use encrypted credentials.  A username and password will not work.

Answer (score 0):

@NotFound has found the answer, I had not seen the method override in the DBContext,`protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)`, it repicks the connection string.
Thank you